# Is there Inequality relating the arithmetic mean (AM) and the dot product

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Is there an inequality of the kind:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}b_{i} \geq C_{1}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}}{n}\right)C_{2}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i}}{n}\right),
$$

i.e., one relating the dot (inner) product $\sum\limits_{i} a_{i}b_{i}$ and the arithmetic means for $A$ and $B$, where the dot product is the greater quantity?

Here, $C_1$ and $C_2$ might not necessarily be constants, but possibly involving the maximum or minimum of $A$ and/or $B$ or something else.

Well-known inequalities like the Rearrangement inequality and the Holder's inequality do not give what I want (neither the [Holder’s reverse inequality](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/119/publn119p211-216.pdf)).

Edit after the comment of @Jack D'Aurizio: the dot product is not $0$.

Comment: In Chebyshev's inequality the numbers in $A$ and $B$ are ordered. I need something in the general case.

Comment: I got for $1\geq a,b,c,d>0$ $$ab+cd-\frac{\left|\left(a-b\right)\left(c-d\right)\left(b-c\right)\left(a-d\right)\right|\left(a+c\right)\left(d+b\right)}{4}\geq 0$$.Can you confirm numerically (I use Desmos not Mathematica)?(+1)For the interesting question .

Comment: You need additional contraints, since the dot product can be zero while $\sum a_n,\sum b_n$ can be positive. For instance $\vec{a}=(1,0),\vec{b}=(0,1)$.

Comment: for $a,b,c,d>0$ we have $ac+bd\ \frac{\frac{\sqrt{\left|\left(a-b\right)\left(b-c\right)\left(c-d\right)\left(a-d\right)\left(a-c\right)\left(b-d\right)\right|}}{2\left(a+b+c+d\right)^{2}}\left(a+c\right)\left(b+d\right)}{4}\geq0$

Comment: @sdd can you confirm ?Thanks .

Comment: @ErikSatie The first one is interesting, even though I hoped to get an expression which do not involve the numbers from A and B, except some min and max values for them. Can you prove it for any given $n$?

Comment: @sdd Oupss in the second one there is a minus after $bd$ sorry !

Comment: Let $A_i$  be positive for $i=1,...,n. $ Let $m=(A_1+...+A_n)/n$ and $M=(1/A_1+...+1/A_n)/n.$ Then $mM\ge 1.$  Proof: In $\Bbb R^n$ with the Cartesian norm, let $x=(\sqrt {A_1},...,\sqrt {A_n})$ and $y=(1/\sqrt {A_1},...,1/\sqrt {A_n}).$ Then  $n^2mM=\|x\|^2\|y\|^2\ge (x\cdot y)^2=n^2.$

Answer (score 3):

If $0 < m_1 \le a_i \le M_1$
and $0 < m_2 \le b_i \le M_2$ for all $i$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
\ge n\left(1 - \frac{(M_1 - m_1)(M_2 - m_2)}{4\sqrt{M_1m_1M_2m_2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right).$$

[1] Dragomir and Khan, Two Discrete Inequalities of Grüss Type Via Pólya-Szegö and Shisha Results for Real Numbers.